# VM powered on by VIX API automation shuts down unexpectedly during large file copy on ESXi 6.0 server

Tags: c#, vsphere, esxi, vix

The following DLLs are being used Vestris.VmWareLib.dll ( 1.7.824.0) and Interop.VixCom.dll (1.0.0.0) for powering on VMs and copying files on ESXi 6.0 server as part of an automation solution using C#.

We have noticed recently that during an automation run when a file of about 390+ Mb approx. is copied on to the VM the VM shuts down unexpectedly. If a smaller file is copied over for example less than 300 Mb the VM does not shut down.

In the VMWare log there are messages “VMware ESX unrecoverable error: (vcpu-0) Unrecoverable memory allocation failure” for when the VM shuts down.

We are using the following library: Vestris.VMWareLib.VMWareVirtualMachine

The crash is occurring on the  CopyFileFromHostToGuest method

public void CopyFileFromHostToGuest(string hostPathName, string guestPathName, int timeoutInSeconds);

When the automation the crash occurs on the same large file all the time, 390+ MB

We migrated the same VM on to an older ESXi server 5.1 and for large and small file size copies the VM does not shut down.

Has anyone else seen issues like this on ESXi 6.0?